# Kafka Producer terminating with 1 message (881 bytes) still in queue or transit

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am pretty new to Kafka and I am getting this message when pushing value to the producer

```
func Produce(topic string, key string, message interface{}) {

    headers := map[string][]byte{
        MSG_HEADER_KEY_CORRELATIONID: []byte("1234"),
        MSG_HEADER_KEY_REQUESTID:     []byte(uuid.NewString()),
        MSG_HEADER_KEY_TESTID:        []byte("456"),
        MSG_HEADER_KEY_MESSAGETYPE:   []byte("TestLookupRequest"),
    }

    kheaders := make([]kafka.Header, 0, len(headers))
    for k, v := range headers {
        kheaders = append(kheaders, kafka.Header{Key: k, Value: v})
    }


    var err error

    servers := "XXXXXX"
    protocol := "SASL_SSL"
    mechanisms := "PLAIN"
    username := "XXXXXXX"
    password := "XXXXXXX"


    Producer, err = kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": servers,
        "security.protocol": protocol,
        "sasl.username":     username,
        "sasl.password":     password,
        "sasl.mechanism":    mechanisms,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer Producer.Close()

    value, _ := json.Marshal(message)

    err = Producer.Produce(&kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
        Key:           []byte("12345"),
        Headers:       kheaders,
        Value:         value,
        Timestamp:     time.Now().UTC(),
        TimestampType: kafka.TimestampCreateTime,
    }, nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Producer.Flush(30)
}
```

**%4|1641074998.615|TERMINATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Producer terminating with 1 message (881 bytes) still in queue or transit: use flush() to wait for outstanding message delivery**

Any help on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, try a longer timeout when `Flush()`; 30ms might not be enough. Or try to use a channel as in this example:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/80c58f81b6cc32d3ed046609bf660a41a061b23d/examples/producer_example/producer_example.go